# Missing multiple perl dependencies

Tags: perl, dependencies, yum, rhel6

I'm trying to install perfSONAR using their official instructions [here](http://docs.perfsonar.net/install_centos.html).
When I run `yum install perfSONAR-Bundles-Complete` I get dozens of errors like the following:

```
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR_PS-Toolkit-ntp-3.5.0.5-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Params::Validate)
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR_PS-Toolkit-3.5.0.5-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Template)
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR-graphs-3.5.0.1-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Data::UUID)
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR_PS-RegularTesting-3.5-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Data::UUID)
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR_PS-Toolkit-Library-3.5.0.5-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Params::Validate)
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR_PS-LSCacheDaemon-3.4.2-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Params::Validate)
Error: Package: perl-perfSONAR_PS-RegularTesting-3.5-1.pSPS.noarch (Internet2)
           Requires: perl(Module::Load)
Error: Package: perl-DateTime-Format-ISO8601-0.07-7.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: perl(DateTime)
```

Perl Version:

```
# perl --version
This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Repositories:

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: changelog, priorities, ps, security
repo id                     repo name                                                              status
Internet2                   Internet2 RPM Repository - software.internet2.edu - main                 333
epel                        Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                         11796
epel-debuginfo              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Debug                  2216
epel-source                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - Source                    0
repolist: 17413
```

I'm running this on a RHEL 6 machine.

**The Quesion:** What do I need to do to resolve the many perl dependency problems listed above?

Comment: Did you add the EPEL release package like the guide said?

Comment: I've updated the question with the repolist.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with red hat packaging, but it looks offhand like you have perl installed via some other mechanism than yum.  in which case, you need to figure out *why* that is before doing anything about it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.   If I do "yum install perl" it reports `Package 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Comment: That's the official perl package. The perfSONAR stuff is coming from the Internet2 repo but that's expected given the directions (though those packages probably shouldn't be marked `el6`). The question is what should be providing things like `perl(Params::Validate)` and `perl(Module::Load)` and those two at least are provided by perl packages provided by CentOS itself. You appear to be missing the normal CentOS base and updates repositories. What files are present in `/etc/yum.repos.d`? What does `rpm -q centos-release` report? You appear to have a slightly busted installation of CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Etan Reisner for the tip to get me headed in the right direction.

The RHEL 6 installation was missing it's base repo.  I opted to add the centos base repo since that's what perfSONAR is expecting.  While this may not be the *best solution it was able to fix my problem.

Copy the following into /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo

```
[centos]
name=CentOS $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/centos/6/os/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Then do a yum clean all and the yum install perfSonar worked!